# Continuous Jcarousel lite clones content near active element

Tags: jquery, css, jcarousel, jcarousellite

Installed a continuous jcarousel lite. From what i understand, it's supposed to clone content in the overflow area, so it would run smoothly. However on my site, it clones li's in visible area. As a result, when the last li comes, there is a blank white space, which takes a couple of seconds to fill with new clones. Did anyone ever run into this problem? How do i fix it? 
May be some way to double clones? Anything else?

Comment: we'll definitely need a link and/or code to look at

Comment: There is too much code involved. here is the link http://birksun.com/pages/look-book  it skips after title 2 (dude in Paris)

Comment: maybe try setting the jcarousel paramater "visible" higher than 2? or remove that parameter all together?

Comment: yeah! looks like that was it. At least scrolling so far. Thanks!!